# How to make image max height equal to its sibling that contains a text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 content">
                <p>
                     //Text From Json File
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 post-img">
                <img src='http://placehold.it/1000/200' />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

I want the image inside the div with class **post-img** not to exceed the hight of the div with class **content** .

I tried:

```
.post 
{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.post .row
{
    display:table-row;
}
.post .row > div
{
    display: table-cell;

}
```

but the image exceed the other div .

Comment: Your div with the class content has not defined any height. Please change your CSS first.

Comment: That's because the text inside it changes dynamically , so it takes the content height

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the effect you want with combination of flex and absolute positioning

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: stretch;
}

.text {
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  // this is so that the .image has any height 
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  position: relative; 
  width: 50%;
}

.image img {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 100%;
  left: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="text">
    Sed nec libero urna. Proin laoreet molestie turpis. Nullam elementum molestie viverra. Praesent sit amet leo eget libero dapibus efficitur. Fusce pulvinar est massa, vel vestibulum velit consectetur vitae. Nam at dolor libero. Fusce eleifend nisl quis
    vehicula ultrices. estie turpis.
    tur.i
  </div>

  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>

</div>
```